# Help to identify a odd skull

Tags: species-identification

[image]I found this skull in the woods, I came across an old stable that the roof was falling in. In the corner there was tree limbs stacked neatly as if something stacked them and the limbs were no bigger than a broomstick. The skull was laying on top of the ground not far from the neatly piled limbs.

I have google photo searched it in several different angles and found nothing similar.
I am at a loss as to what type of animal this could be. It is just very oddly Proportioned.

It does not resemble anything I have reached. Please help I identifying this skull. [image] [image]

[image]

Comment: I live in oklahoma by the way

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the Outdoors SE. If you could provide photos for other angles and higher resolution for each, that would help with ID. You could also request migration to the Biology SE, which has ID tags too.

Comment: Also, would need some sense of scale - is this 2 inches or two feet long; can't tell from the photo.

Comment: It is 6 to 8 inches long

Answer (score 3):

Very hard to say from the shape it is in.

Some observations:

- The molars suggest it's a herbivore, the teeth look similar to what I know from the skulls of sheep/goats/roe/deer/...
- Seems to have no signs of horns or antlers.
- From the size I would say it is about the size of a roe/sheep/goat.

My best guess:
Since roe deer only live in Eurasia and not Oklahoma US I'd figure this skull could be from a small (young?) female deer or similar, or - if livestock is more likely - a variant of goat or sheep without horns.

Comment: I think White tailed deer juvenile or doe. No sign of antlers, teeth look right (curved row rather than straight) and cranium is about right too.